# Reshaping data and generating IDs with column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```html
DF <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"126    D1  181 N1  225 P1

A   2   B   9   A   11
D   3   B   12  A   11
"
)
```

I want to get the following table, but I struggle to it

```html
DF <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"ID Class   D1  Time    N1
126 A   2   D   3
181 B   9   B   12
225 A   11  A   11"

)
```

!26,181 and 225 get the ID column and based on that the table is completed. Can we do it in R

Comment: Are you sure that your first `DF` example has headers?

Comment: Yes, they are headers

Comment: In your real data, are the initial headers really `c("X126", "D1", "X181", "N1", "X225", "P1")`?

Comment: Yes, they are correct,

Comment: `P1` disappears. `D1` is "over" `2` and `3`, but in the results it is the header for values `2`, `9`, and `11`. This seems inconsistent, is that somewhat arbitrary?

Comment: they are random data. it's ok no need editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the base R option as below works for your purpose

```
type.convert(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      split.default(DF, cumsum(grepl("X\\d+", names(DF)))),
      function(x) data.frame(t(c(head(names(x), 1), t(x))))
    )
  ),
  as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 X126  A  2  D  3
2 X181  B  9  B 12
3 X225  A 11  A 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with headers turned *off*, since it's easier to deal with static/known headers and keeping data as data.

```r
DF <- read.table(header = FALSE, text =
"126    D1  181 N1  225 P1
A   2   B   9   A   11
D   3   B   12  A   11")
```

Then the work:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # map, transpose

split.default(DF, (seq_len(ncol(DF)) - 1) %/% 2) %>%
  map(., setNames, c("V1", "V2")) %>%
  lapply(., function(x) c(unlist(t(x)))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  transpose()
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1 126 D1  A  2  D  3
# 2 181 N1  B  9  B 12
# 3 225 P1  A 11  A 11
```

And you can name them (and omit columns) as needed.

Comment: could we do better as I have 62  columns?

Comment: See my edit, it now doesn't care how many columns you have, as long as it is effectively 2 columns per output-row.

Comment: I have just copied-paste your codes and I get a strange output, not as you have shown

Comment: I'm not sure what I can do without knowing anything about this "strange output". Providing "representative sample data" is often difficult, for many reasons, perhaps we're hitting one of them now. Is it possible to provide the top 3 lines *verbatim* of the input file (not `read.table` code)?

Comment: [1]]
[[1]]$`0`
[1] "126"

[[1]]$`1`
[1] "181"

[[1]]$`2`
[1] "225